# update custom listview failed while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listView and in every view item of the listView is a seekbar and a button. when the user click on a button of a row of listview the `rowView` of the item is sent to a class(`voicePlayer`) for update the seekbar of the rowView. the class updates the seekbar correctly by if i scroll the listview that the view gets invisible, the progressing(update) of the seekbar is stopped. sounds like the elements of the view obtain new address during the scroll that the old ones are invalid, How should i update the UI of view even when thay are invisible?

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice_player_listview, null,true);
    final SeekBar voice_player_seekbar =(SeekBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.voice_player_seekbar);
    final ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.download_play_icon);
    icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        new voicePlayer(voice_id.get(position), rowView);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
```

**`voicePlayer`**

```
 class voicePlayer {
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 SeekBar seekbar;
 TextView voice_duration;
 ImageView icon;
 WavesAPI.viewHolder rowView;
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
public void getViews()
{
    this.seekbar= (seekbar) rowView.findViewById ...
    this.voice_duration=(TextView) rowView.findViewById ...
    this.icon=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById ...
}
public voicePlayer(String voice_id,WavesAPI.View rowView) {
    this.rowView=rowView;
    getViews();
                /*mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                 ... play the voice

                */

                    this.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    this.updateSeekbar();


                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

    }


}
private void updateSeekbar()
{

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int position=// calculate the position of the seekbar
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                seekbar.setProgress(position);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                voice_duration.setText("duration ...");
            }
        }
    };

    handler.post(runnable);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list that you maintain in the recyclerview needs to be updated with the latest seekbar position, this is because of the way the recyclerview works, for performance it will bind your view and unbind it as and when needed, during unbind the data for that row is cleared and the view is recycled with new data which it fetches from the list, so if the list is not updated you will see older data.

Update the list, notify the change to the updater and that should work.

```
private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

    List<Data> dataList;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       CustomData data =  dataList.get(position);

       // existing code

       int currentSeekarProgress = data.getSeekbarProgress();
       seekBar.setProgress(currentSeekarProgress);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

You would need to save the latest seekbar position in your data list and then fetch it in `getView`. This would allow you to update and persist the position even when the row is scrolled off the screen.

Comment: i didn't get what i have to do exactly. i just want the updater class to update the list item even if the list item is invisible

Comment: when a seekbar is updating, getView is call freuqently, but the `position` value is 0,1,2. but my listview item count is 100 and mylistview fits only 3 items on the screen

Comment: anybody to response?

Comment: @amirghorbani this `voicePlayer` does it update the data list maintained by the list view?

Comment: yes, `voicePlayer` gets the `rowView` and update the seekbar of the rowView.

Comment: @amirghorbani I've updated the answer with a snippet of what the final solution could be.

Comment: but still my problem exist. assume `voicePlayer` is playing some voice and updating the corresponding seekbar. i give the `voicePlayer` rowView to update its seekbar. if i scroll off the row, seems new address would be allocated to the rowView that the old one is invalid. another problem is, when `voicePlayer` is updaing the seekbar, `getView` frequently gets called with `position` 0,1,2. because my screen and list view fit 3 items.

Comment: somebody answer please

Comment: You are sort of right that the rowView gets a new address per say and yes `voicePlayer` does update the seekbar but once `rowView` is scrolled off the screen, the view is destroyed and recycled. Now suppose the seekbar was at position `60%` before it was scrolled off and destroyed, you would need to set the seekbar back at that position for that particular row, correct? In order to do that where would the data come from? the dataset? so you need to update your dataset with the latest seekbar positions.

Comment: Post the code of `voicePlayer` for more clarity of the viewers here.

Comment: i just updated the post. this is true that i must get the last position of the seekbar to apply them when the row is created or recycled. i haven't mention this process code here but i have already used a dataset to apply this. but my problem is when the row seekbar is updating by the `voicePlayer` and scroll off. then when i scroll back to the row that was playing, the row seekbar is not updating but the voice is playing. sounds like the previous rowView i passed to voicePlayer is no longer valid and usable